# How to translate conditions (without brackets) correctly?

Tags: c#

I have condition, where are no `(` `)` brackets inside coded by programmer... How can I bracket such ugly coded correctly?

```
if( c_1 && c_2 || c_3 || c_4 && c_5 || c_6 && c_7 || c_8 || c_9 && c_10)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&&` has higher precedence<sup>1</sup> in C# than `||`. That means your expression is effectively:

```
if ((c_1 && c_2) || c_3 || (c_4 && c_5) || (c_6 && c_7) || c_8 || (c_9 && c_10))
```

For further readability, I'd probably extract conditions into local variables with meaningful names. For example:

```
bool recentlyActive = (c_1 && c_2) || c_3;
bool passwordDisabled = (c_4 && c_5) || (c_6 && c_7);
bool userBanned =  c_8 || (c_9 && c_10);
if (recentlyActive || passwordDisabled || userBanned)
{
    ...
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Precedence in C# is documented in the specification, but it really comes directly out of the grammar. I'm glad of that documentation though, because I wouldn't want to have to read the grammar every time I wanted to understand how operators bind...